# How to create custom field search in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need to create a custom advanced search for my wp site. I have to show search result in cpt (search-home.php). My form has a lot of fields containing different meta values.
I know i must use `pre_get_posts` but I can not use it well.
Form fields data sends by get method and I need to filter wp query by using `pre_get_posts`, but not all fields are required and so they may not send.

```
$query->set( 'meta_query', array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => 'name', 
        'value' => $_GET['name']
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'family', 
        'value' => $_GET['family']

    )
) );
```

First, I need to filter `pre_get_posts` in my CPT (search-home.php page).
Second, I need to filter the wp query by `$_GET` values . The problem is that when a value is not sent by the get method in url (for example family), wp query return null values, while I need to show post by exited meta (for example name), number of fields is high, Because of this i cannot use `isset` to check values. 
Please help me thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like if a field is not passed, you only want to filter by the fields that are passed and ignore the non passed fields, is that right? If not, let me know, and I’ll adjust my answer.

You can take care of missing fields without a separate`isset` line on every field. See below:
Create an array of ALL field names:

```
$field_names = array('family', 'name', 'country');
$meta_query = array('relation' => 'OR');
foreach ($field_names as $field_name) {
  if (isset($_GET[$field_name])) { 
    $meta_query[] = array('key' => $field_name, 'value' => $_GET[$field_name]);
  }
}

$args = array(
    'meta_query' => $meta_query,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: tnxxxxx @Noah, how can i define pre_get_posts action in functions.php to filter wp query in my cpt? (home-search.php)

Comment: That depends. How are you pulling in the posts? Is this a default WP template that has a posts query? Are you using a short code?

Comment: simple wp_query class

Comment: If that is the case, you can just use the meta query within the WP Query. No need for pre get posts

Comment: Yes it's the same, Thank you for taking the time . have a nice day

Comment: So I don’t know what the rest of the query looks like, but I’ve updated my answer to use a wp query.